# Couchbase cbdocloader does not import json files

Tags: json, couchbase

I have a list of JSON files that failed to be imported with cbdocloader (couchbase 4.1 ce).

JSON files are valid jsons, and they look something like this:

```
{ "created" : "1462963148", "username" : "bob", "value" : "44.0"}
```

When I try to run:

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/cbdocloader -u Administrator -p admin123 -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -b mydata ./test
```

I get:

```
[2016-08-26 13:31:28,575] - [rest_client] [139944520083200] - INFO - 

existing buckets : [u'sensordata']
[2016-08-26 13:31:28,580] - [rest_client] [139944520083200] - INFO - http://127.0.0.1:8091//pools/default/buckets with param: proxyPort=11211&bucketType=membase&authType=sasl&name=mydata&replicaNumber=1&saslPassword=&ramQuotaMB=100
[2016-08-26 13:31:28,597] - [rest_client] [139944520083200] - INFO - existing buckets : [u'mydata', u'sensordata']
[2016-08-26 13:31:28,597] - [rest_client] [139944520083200] - INFO - found bucket mydata
..bucket creation is successful
.
bucket: test, msgs transferred...
       :                total |       last |    per sec
 byte  :                    0 |          0 |        0.0
done
```

Even though the bucket is created successfully **no data is imported**.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

After investigation I've found out that JSON documents that are imported must contain ***id*** field. Otherwise, cbdocloader silently fails to import them. At least that is the case in couchbase 4.1 community edition.

Also, user must be careful not to add trailing slash at the end of the cbdocloader command. `/opt/couchbase/bin/cbdocloader -u Administrator -p admin123 -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -b mydata ./test` is not the same as `/opt/couchbase/bin/cbdocloader -u Administrator -p admin123 -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -b mydata ./test/` (note the / at the end of the second command)